# ORA-01847 - SELECT returns no result

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table TIGER in a schema OFO.

I have a column AS_OF_DATE with a data type DATE.

I have values in this column as follows:

```
2017-01-31 00:00:00
2017-02-28 00:00:00
2017-03-31 00:00:00
```

But I also have 1 unwanted value (that I want to delete, but I want to `SELECT` it via sql statement first):

```
 0030-09-20 17:00:00
```

I use TOAD to see these values in Schema Browser.

I can also use a select to return me the values, this one works, it returns me results:

```
SELECT AS_OF_DATE from OFO.TIGER where AS_OF_DATE='2017-01-31'
```

But the following select does not work:

```
SELECT AS_OF_DATE from OFO.TIGER where AS_OF_DATE='0030-09-20'
```

It gives me an error:

> ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month tips

The date is obviously in wrong format, but somehow someone managed to add that value, now I want to delete it (all the rows that have `AS_OF_DATE='0030-09-20'`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your queries are relying on the evil implicit data type conversion. `'2017-01-31'` is a string constant **not** a `DATE` constant. The rules for this conversion are defined by the NLS settings of the *client*.

You have two ways of specifying a proper DATE constant in Oracle:

#### Use an ANSI SQL date literal

```
SELECT * 
FROM ofo.tiger 
WHERE as_of_date = DATE '2017-01-31';
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM ofo.tiger 
WHERE as_of_date = DATE '0030-09-20';
```

An ANSI DATE literal **always** specifies the DATE in the ISO format `yyyy-mm-dd` thus there are no implicit conversion rules regarding 1930 vs. 2030

#### Use Oracle's `to_date()` function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ofo.tiger 
WHERE as_of_date = to_date('0030-09-20', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

By specifying the [format mask](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#CDEHIFJA) the year is also un-ambigous and no implicit conversion will take place.

Comment: Thanks for providing not just a solution but a clear explanation. Now it works as it's supposed to.... your answer is the most accurate, although JohnHC's also gives me the same results, but it's not that accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I would write the query as follows, TRUNC statement will rip date only from the datetime column and it would suit your need correctly :

```
SELECT * 
from ofo.tiger 
where TRUNC(as_of_date) = TRUNC(to_date('0030-09-20', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of selecting for what it is, select what it isn't:

```
select AS_OF_DATE
from OFO.TIGER
where not AS_OF_DATE between '1970-01-01' and '2017-12-31'
```